# Accessing the Checkbox inside Datagrid on Button click Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

```
  bool checked1 = (datagrid1.FindControl("CheckBox1") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox).Checked;
```

I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**How do i access from inside the DataGrid whether the CheckBox is Check Or Not?**

**NOTE:** The CheckBox is inside the HeaderTemplate

Comment: You should provide datagrid layout so we can help. No it is not clear where is the checkbox.

Comment: Its inside the header template in datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to iterate across the **[DataGridItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.items%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

```
foreach( DataGridItem di in datagrid1.Items )
    {
        CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)di.FindControl("CheckBox1") ;
        if( chkBx !=null && chkBx.Checked )
        {
            //isChecked
        }
    }
```

Comment: can i do this without DatagridItems?